# Executing r.viewshed (GRASS) in R

Tags: qgis, r, grass-gis, viewshed

What libraries do I need to execute this GRASS tool (or any other) from an script in R ? Has anybody try to compare performance between using r.viewshed from QGIS and r.viewshed from R ?

Comment: Look at [R statistics/rgrass7](https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/R_statistics/rgrass7)

Comment: I would like to execute the tool r.viewshed like I do within QGIS. Just like  "> function(parameter1, parameter2, ...)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have a R and GRASS version installed. Check the compatibility among them.
Then you can use:

```
library(rgrass7)

loc <- initGRASS('C://Program Files//GRASS GIS 7.4.0', # Path to your GRASS folder
                   gisDbase='D://grass', # Yor grass DB
                   location = 'MAGNA2', # Grass location
                   mapset ='PERMANENT', # Grass mapset
                   override = TRUE) # 

## Calculate new layer. A raster ER is created into GRASS DB, not into R environment
execGRASS("r.mapcalc", expression = 'ER=if(P_over_L>0.316,ptrast/sqrt(0.9+P_over_L^2),ptrast)', flags = 'overwrite')
execGRASS("r.watershed", elevation='dem', flow = 'flow', depression = 'depression', flags = 'help')

execGRASS('g.list', mapset = 'PERMANENT', type = 'raster', intern = TRUE)
execGRASS('g.list', mapset = 'PERMANENT', type = 'vector', intern = TRUE)

## List available layers. Use ´intern = TRUE´ for bring the list into R
layers <- execGRASS('g.list', mapset = 'PERMANENT', type = 'all', intern = TRUE)

## Bring GRASS layer into R
exampleVEC <- readVECT('basin_1101_11017010')

## Bring GRASS layer into R
exampleR <- readRAST('ER)
```

Hope you find it useful.

Answer (score 1):

Quite a few GIS articles cover this. I think Riggs paper in TGIS is likely the one you want.

> https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/j.1467-9671.2007.01040.x

Comment: Sorry but, this is not what I'm asking about performance. I mean the execution time for r.viewshed in R or in QGIS.